# CollectionView crash in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view that crashes with the error 'EXC_BREAKPOINT' when I scroll.

The line it crashes on in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is:

`let message = searchResults.objectAtIndex(indexPath.item) as MessageObject`

The line that precedes that just sets up the cell:

`var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCell`

Basically I'm just getting an object from an array. The `numberOfItemsInSection` is equal to the count of this array.

Comment: can you add the crash logs?

Comment: Yeah, you need to add way more info... I'd recommend adding all the relevant code.

Comment: I get nothing in the debugger. Just a green coloured message at that line with ```Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode0x1000f0ae4)```

Comment: the run is stoping at a automatic breakpoint you need to press the continue button 2-3 more times, or just disable all breakpoints

Comment: This is just the second line of the method - I've added the first to see if that helps. Any other specific code you'd like to see? It's really just a standard collection view.

Comment: @YuviGr That's what I thought as earlier today I had an 'all exceptions' breakpoint set. But it's been removed and I've tried continuing several times but it's stuck at that point. I also tried restarting XCode.

Comment: ok, so you need to check 2 things. 1) if the "searchResults" object is not nil 2) if the indexPath.item value isn't higher then the searchResults.count

Comment: @YuviGr I just put a couple of NSLogs in and searchResults is always '32'. Index path crashes at '13'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry guys it was mostly my fault. The reason the error wasn't appearing in the console was because I was in release mode instead of debug mode. Strangely I was still seeing some NSLogs - Swift seems to print those regardless of your scheme.

Anyway the issue in the console is:

`unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I should be able to track that down quite easily.